# Need to send an email to Form respondents based on question answer

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I need some help! I am trying to automate sending an email to the form respondent if they select any of the AcLab Session Full answers.  The possible answers range from blank up to AcLab Session Full19

I successfully got it to send an email on every response, only problem is I need it to send only when the respondent selects a particular thing, and not everything.

Now I've messed up the code and it isn't working at all!

Here is where I think I've messed up (keep in mind, I'm not a developer or coder, this is pieced together from many different places and is likely incorrect)

```
function AutoConfirmation(e)
{
      var theirFirst = e.values[2];
      var theirEmail = e.values[1];
      var theirSession= e.values[4];
      var subject = "Action Required: Your Selected AcLab Session is Full";
      var message = "Thank you " + theirFirst + ",<br> <br> The AcLab session that you have selected for this week is full. " 
      var cosmetics = {htmlBody: message};
      
 if (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').getRange('Form Responses 1!E2:E10000').getValue(theirSession)=""||"AcLab Session Full1"||"AcLab Session Full2"||"AcLab Session Full3"||"AcLab Session Full4"||"AcLab Session Full5"||"AcLab Session Full6"||"AcLab Session Full7") return;
MailApp.sendEmail (theirEmail, subject, message, cosmetics);}
```

Comment: If you want  a better answer that that which is provided below then ask a better question because it's not clear to me what your asking

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send the email when a condition is met, you need to place that code inside the IF:

```
if (condition) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(theirEmail, subject, message, cosmetics);
}
```

In your case, this condition would be whether the selected value is one of the session values specified in the form answer (`theirSession`):

```
if (theirSession === "AcLab Session Full1" || 
    theirSession === "AcLab Session Full2" || 
    theirSession === "AcLab Session Full3" || 
    theirSession === "AcLab Session Full4" || 
    theirSession === "AcLab Session Full5" || 
    theirSession === "AcLab Session Full6" || 
    theirSession === "AcLab Session Full7") {
  MailApp.sendEmail(theirEmail, subject, message, cosmetics);
}
```

Alternatively, you can add all the options to an array and look for the desired value in it using [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var sessions = ["AcLab Session Full1", 
                "AcLab Session Full2", 
                "AcLab Session Full3", 
                "AcLab Session Full4", 
                "AcLab Session Full5", 
                "AcLab Session Full6", 
                "AcLab Session Full7"];
if (sessions.indexOf(theirSession) >= 0) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(theirEmail, subject, message, cosmetics);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I went with the simple code of the if condition and it works!  You have helped a teacher figure out a big problem for her school, and I am thankful (and I'm starting to understand what is happening here in the script a bit). Many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful! In this case, please consider accepting it as the answer to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers